# CSS - Giving border to li

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to give border to my list. I'm using li for that. I have created something and I have attached that above, you check that. I did that using extra div's. But I need to remove all the extra div's and need to give border like this using css only. Can we do that?

```css
.counter {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.counter ul {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.counter li {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 100px;
}

.counter li .c-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: stretch;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.line-1 {
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 65%;
}

.line-2 {
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 35%;
}

.line-3 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 1px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  right: 35%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.line-4 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 1px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  right: 65%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="counter">
  <div class="line-1"></div>
  <div class="line-2"></div>
  <div class="line-3"></div>
  <div class="line-4"></div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="c-grid"> 1 </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="c-grid"> 2 </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="c-grid"> 3 </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="c-grid"> 4 </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="c-grid"> 5 </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="c-grid"> 6 </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="c-grid"> 7 </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="c-grid"> 8 </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="c-grid"> 9 </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: please show the css you have written so far

Comment: I have attached all those things bro :) And it's simple.

Comment: line-1, line-2, etc are the div's that i used to create border.

Comment: i can't find any css but have you tried something like li{border: 1px solid black}

Comment: your height: 100%; wont work unless provided a fixed height to its parent so you are unable to see anything, also can you please show what are you trying to acheive

Comment: @Coder95 - we are not necessarily "guys" (I am, but still) or "bros" - could you post an image too?

Comment: Actually I want to create something like this without using any extra div. Using border also fine. But how I don't know.

Comment: @Coder95 you forgot to post image

Comment: http://dev.netbramha.in/projects/nb-test/image.png This is the link for image

Comment: Link does not work. Upload it here

Answer (score 0):

Add `list-style-position:inside;`

```
.borderlist {
list-style-position:inside;
border: 1px solid black;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here I have removed the four `div` lines and used `li` border you can add as much as row in it and it will continue to follow
Also added `box-sizing: border-box;` to avoid the breaking of grid

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.counter {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.counter ul {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

.counter li {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33333%;
  height: 100px;
}

.counter li .c-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: stretch;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

li:nth-child(3n) {
  border-right: none;
}

li:nth-last-child(-n+3),
li:nth-last-child(-n+2),
li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="counter">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="c-grid"> 1 </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="c-grid"> 2 </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="c-grid"> 3 </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="c-grid"> 4 </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="c-grid"> 5 </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="c-grid"> 6 </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="c-grid"> 7 </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="c-grid"> 8 </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="c-grid"> 9 </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Anytime !! If this has solved your problem please accept the answer.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to use `CSS Grid` with some `nth-child` border styles. Using this approach, we can remove:

- unnecessary `<div>`s
- floats
- redundant styles

```css
html, body, ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

ul > li {
  padding: 20px 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* First 6 items */
ul > li:nth-child(-n + 6)  {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

/* Every 3rd item, starting from the 2nd item */
ul > li:nth-child(3n + 2) {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;  
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
</ul>
```

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/2hg9zr4q/3/

Comment: @JoykalInfotech That's 100% untrue. If you add anything inside the `<li>`, the grid is intact. You would never want to add anything but an `<li>` as a direct child of `<ul>`.